# Ansible expect when command asks twice the same question

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to automate VirtualGL configuration using command vglserver_config. This script uses this menu :

```
1) Configure server for use with VirtualGL (GLX + EGL back ends)
2) Unconfigure server for use with VirtualGL (GLX + EGL back ends)
3) Configure server for use with VirtualGL (EGL back end only)
4) Unconfigure server for use with VirtualGL (EGL back end only)
X) Exit

Choose:
```

I need to feed two different answers to the "Choose:" question :

- '1' first time, to configure VirtualGL, followed by actual responses of configuration script (see below)
- 'x' when exiting the command

Here's the task I've come to:

```
  - name: configure VirtualGL (vglserver_config)
    ansible.builtin.expect:
      command: "{{ vglserver_config_cmd }}"
      responses:
        (.*)Choose:(.*): 1
        (.*)Continue?(.*): y
        (.*)Restrict 3D X server access to vglusers group (recommended)?(.*): y
        (.*)Restrict framebuffer device access to vglusers group (recommended)?(.*): y
        (.*)Disable XTEST extension (recommended)?(.*): y
        (.*)Choose:(.*): x
```

This does not work: as the entry `(.*)Choose!(.*):` is duplicated (Ansible complains about that), the command is answered 'X' by expect module, and thus nothing happen.

I tried an alternative code:

```
  - name: configure VirtualGL (vglserver_config)
    ansible.builtin.expect:
      command: "{{ vglserver_config_cmd }}"
      responses:
          Question:
            - 1
            - y
            - y
            - y
            - y
            - x
```

But this syntax is incorrect. Ansible throws an error.

How can I solve this issue ?

Thx !
Jose

PS. Edited the 2nd code example to reflect the exact one I also tested (same error raised by Ansible)

Comment: For the alternate syntax, when you do provide a list you need to provide a `Question` key indentend in the `responses` one. See the examples in the docs https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

Ok...
Why would I want to use expect module for a command that has unattended mode parameters...
I'm so dumb.

I've changed the "expect" task to a "command" with proper parameters.